# How to convert a .odex file to a dex file

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to decompile a system app. Unfortunately there is no classes.dex for this particular system app. There is only a *.odex. I know I have to deodex this so that I get a .dex file. I have looked at smali but evry time I run it I get the following error.
[Baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) tells me to use the following syntax:(I am running on windows hence I cant use the bash wrapper provided)

```
java -jar baksmali-1.3.3.jar -x name.odex
```

However it throws a top level exception:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
org.jf.dexlib.Util.ExceptionWithContext: regCount does not match the number of a
rguments of the method
```

Comment: This really is beyond the scope of this site. This site is primarily concerned with helping people use their Android devices. A site like xda-developers is probably better suited for this.

Comment: Okay. I didnt know that. Will post it there.

Comment: Since this is also apparently a programming issue, [so] might also be an appropriate venue.

Comment: Okay. I guess I wont try to delete it since I have got a couple of answers here which may be helpful. Thanks for the heads up:)

Answer (score 2):

Might be better to use the all in one [tool](https://github.com/sonyericssondev/ApkAnalyser/wiki) that could help you published courtesy of Sony Ericsson and its open source.

To quote from their wiki page:

> Support odex applications and libraries

Use this for the right reason, not for the wrong reason (such as rampant piracy etc, and in no way am I implying anything)

In fact this saved my bacon at one stage when I could not remember whether I bundled a jpeg in a apk that I built and had to go through that tool to confirm my "blonde moment"

***Edit:*** Another thing I noticed - you're missing a switch, for example, this was pulled from [here](http://madteam.co/forum/tutorials/how-to-deodex-an-odex-file/) (*Credit to the Madteam forum*):

> java -jar baksmali.jar -d C:\framework -x TouchWiz30Launcher.odex

You need the *framework-res.apk* (this can be found in */system/framework* on the handset) in place hence the ***-d*** directory

Comment: looks like a glorified apktool to me. dex2jar was also helpful at one time but i can't really remember if it also did odex.

Comment: Nope. dex2jar does not support odex. Otherwise it really is a good tool when combined with the power of jad or jd-gui

Comment: The switch you are talking about is not really required is what I understand from this article-http://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions